# Checking numbers input with Regex - C#

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, validating

I've always been using Regex to check for user's input validity, ie checking for a correct mail adress, serial number, etc...

Now I want to check that the user input is, let's say, a number contained between : 78 and 143.

We're not quite analysing the user's input, but interpreting it and analysing after...

Would the Regex still be useful ? Would it be a good practice to use Regexs in that case ?

What would be the best way to control that kind of input ?

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 1):

I dont think regex is useful in this case. You can just use normal **>** and **<** operators for your cause.

Probably if you get this validation on client side, that will just be good too (unless your case is user-specific and needs server side validation)

Comment: Actually, It's just a simple example of the different cases I have to solve... Of course I could simply use that, but the entries will be much more complicated than 78 or 143.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) instead of the RegularExpressionValidator.  The Regex adds complexity to a simple problem, so it's less useful, and therefore, not the best practice.

Comment: Thank you, see my comment on Sachin Shanbhag's answer. I entered a simple example on purpose...